# Duplicate last file in directory a couple of times while incrementing the name

Tags: bash

I've two directories that contain an unequal number of pictures:

```
ls plot1 -> 0001.png 0002.png 0003.png 0004.png 0005.png
ls plot2 -> 0001.png 0002.png 0003.png
```

The picture-names are numbers with leading zeros and the prefix `.png`. I need to duplicate the last picture in the `plot2` directory so many times, that the number of files is equal to the directory `plot1`. The filename must be incremented: `plot2/0003.png` gets copied to `0004.png` and `0005.png`.

```
ls plot1 -> 0001.png 0002.png 0003.png 0004.png 0005.png
ls plot2 -> 0001.png 0002.png 0003.png 0004.png 0005.png #last two files are copies of 0003.png
```

How can I do that? (Especially incrementing the filename?)

I know that I can get the last file in a folder by using find. But that's where my knowledge ends...

```
find plot2 -type f | sort -V | tail -n 1
-> ./0003.png
```

**Edit**
I think a potential solution would be something like this:

```
delat= $(expr `ls plot1 | wc -l` - `ls plot2 | wc -l`)
for i in find . -type f | sort -V | tail -n $delta
  cp `find plot2 -type f | sort -V | tail -n 1` i
```

It stores the difference from `plot1` and `plot2` in `$delta` and then make a copy of the last available plot in `plot2` for each filename that exceeds `$delta`. However, it does not work yet. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job. However there is very likely a better way.

```
delta="$((`ls plot1 | wc -l` - `ls plot2 | wc -l`))"
last=$(find plot2 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort -V | tail -n 1)
for i in $(find plot1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort -V | tail -n $delta)
do
  cp plot2/$last plot2/$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have the same filenames in `plot2` and want to copy the file `plot2/0003.png` for that, you can copy to all files that not yet exist. You do not need to test `[ -f "${file}" ]` when you can use the `cp -n` option:

```
for file in plot1; do
   cp -n plot2/0003.png "${file/plot1/plot2}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getlast() { ls -1 "$1" | sort -n | tail -1; };

plot1=$(getlast plot1); plot2=$(getlast plot2);
target=${plot1%.png}; from=${plot2%.png};
for ((i=$from+1; i<=$target; i++)); do 
    n=$(printf "%04d.png" $i); 
    cp plot2/$plot2 plot2/$n; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses just Bash and 'cp':

```
# Protect against empty directories
shopt -s nullglob

plot1_files=( plot1/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png )
plot2_files=( plot2/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png )

declare -i plot1_count=${#plot1_files[*]}
declare -i plot2_count=${#plot2_files[*]}

# Exit if the directories are not set up appropriately
(( plot2_count == 0 )) && exit 1
(( plot2_count >= plot1_count )) && exit 1

plot2_lastfile=${plot2_files[-1]}
plot2_lastbase=${plot2_lastfile##*/}
declare -i plot2_lastnum=10#${plot2_lastbase%.png}

plot2_srcfile=$plot2_lastfile

while (( plot2_count < plot1_count )) ; do
    plot2_lastnum+=1
    printf -v plot2_lastfile 'plot2/%04d.png' "$plot2_lastnum"
    cp -- "$plot2_srcfile" "$plot2_lastfile"
    plot2_count+=1
done
```

It does not assume that the image numbers are contiguous.  It does not assume that all of the image file names in plot2 also exist in plot1.  For instance, it works with:

```
ls plot1 -> 0001.png  0003.png  0005.png  0007.png  0009.png
ls plot2 -> 0006.png  0008.png  0010.png
```